# data.sql is not executed during unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, h2

I am implementing a unit test for a basic CRUD API. I have a class called Classified which includes an instance of a class named Category inside it. Both of them have their own databases. To initialize Category database I created a "data.sql" file under resources folder. It worked splendidly during normal execution but it is not being executed when I run my test. I am using h2 in-memory database.

data.sql content:

```
insert into CATEGORY values (1, 'Real Estate');
insert into CATEGORY values (2, 'Vehicle');
insert into CATEGORY values (3, 'Shopping');
insert into CATEGORY values (4, 'Other');
```

test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ClassifiedServiceTest {
@Mock
private ClassifiedRepository classifiedRepository;
@Mock
private ClassifiedHistoryRepository classifiedHistoryRepository;
@Mock
private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
@InjectMocks
private ClassifiedService classifiedService;

@Test
public void createClassifiedTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // This method throws an exception related to CATEGORY table being empty
    }
}
```

I tried adding @Sql("data.sql") to Test class but then I got

```
org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TestContextTransactionUtils - Caught exception while retrieving DataSource for test context [DefaultTestContext@1189dd52 testClass = ClassifiedServiceTest, testInstance = com.sahibinden.codecase.services.ClassifiedServiceTest@1133ec6e, testMethod = createAndDeactivateClassifiedTest@ClassifiedServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@36bc55de testClass = ClassifiedServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@a4102b8, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7a52f2a2, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@75f32542, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@229d10bd], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener.recordApplicationEvents' -> false, 'org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.mocks' -> org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine$$Lambda$113/0x0000000800da41d8@355e34c7]]
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' 
available
```

How can I configure my test class to run data.sql and populate the database before running these tests

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use `@SpringBootTest` to let Spring Boot autoconfigure your embedded datasource using H2.
Spring Boot will then execute your `schema.sql` and `data.sql` to setup your H2 database automatically.
If you use `@SpringBootTest`, you have to inject your bean using `@Autowired` instead of `@InjectMocks` and you don't need to mock others beans.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class ClassifiedServiceTest {

@Autowired
private ClassifiedService classifiedService;

@Test
public void createClassifiedTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // This method throws an exception related to CATEGORY table being empty
    }
}
```

You can also use slice testing if starting your Spring boot app is too long. For that, you can do :

```java
@DataJpaTest
@Import(ClassifiedServiceImpl.class) // You need the implementation here 
public class ClassifiedServiceTest {

@Autowired
private ClassifiedService classifiedService;

@Test
public void createClassifiedTest() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // This method throws an exception related to CATEGORY table being empty
    }
}
```

It will only setup all the things needed to using JPA and load your `ClassifiedService` in the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Like says Farid you cannot use Spring data in Unit Test but in Integration Test instead with

> @SpringBootTest

for mount SpringBoot context